# Are micro-USB intervalometers for Samsung and Sony compatible?

Tags: sony, compatibility, intervalometer, samsung

I have an old Samsung NX1000 that is just sitting around doing nothing. I'd like to do some timelapse photography with it -and need to get an intervalometer - looking on Amazon and eBay I can see some suitable and all have a micro USB plug to connect to the camera. Now I also seen an intervalometer for the Sony A7 but at nearly half the price and looking in to product this too connects using a micro USB plug.

So can I use the cheaper Sony intervalometer on the Samsung camera?

Answer (score 3):

> So can I use the cheaper Sony intervalometer on the Samsung camera?

**No, you cannot.**

While the Sony multi-terminal connector looks like it's micro-USB, it isn't, really. [doc-diy.net's list of shutter release pinouts](http://www.doc-diy.net/photo/remote_pinout/) has [an image of the connector](http://www.doc-diy.net/photo/remote_pinout/sony_rm-vpr1_remote_pinout.jpg), and its wiring is nothing like a micro USB connector.  It has an additional 10 pins (15 in all) vs. the standard 5 used in micro-USB.

Samsung's cable release uses a standard micro-USB connector, as shown in [a diagram on instructables.com](http://www.instructables.com/id/Samsung-NX-DSLR-Camera-Trigger-Cable/).